# pyspark deleted directory due to ill-formatted save - recovery of data possible?

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery, recovery

I am new to hadoop and spark. When I was running a test in pyspark after installation, I wrote a test file out to a directory using an ill-formatted save command. Instead of saving to a specific file, I saved to an existing work directory, causing spark to erase part of the directory (only part because the command was cancelled via ctrl+C).

Is it possible to recover any of the lost data?

The pyspark command was:

```
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("/some_work_directory")
```

the directory `/some_work_directory` was partially overwritten but not completely deleted as it is a large directory and I cancelled the command when it hung.

Comment: What were you writing to? SSD? What OS is this?

Comment: written to HDD via Linux Mint 20.3